# How to make custom plugin accessible for subscribers?

Tags: wordpress, roles, capability

I have created a plugin into my local WordPress site. When I login into Admin section as an Admin/Editor/Author, I am able to access the plugin. But, when I login as a subscriber I cannot access it.

My Question: How can I make my custom plugin accessible for subscribers?

My efforts: I have looked into `map_meta_cap()` function of Wordpress but I was not able to make it work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If I wanted to test and simulate your problem, what's the code? Ie: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @brasofilo: Thank you for response. You can take example of any plugin. None of them are accessible to subscribers. If you still need my custom plugin I can share the code with you.